# How to instantiate a view controller with tab and nav controller for deep linking?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm implementing deep linking for my app and having trouble instantiating my app properly. For my app link, it is opening up a detail page for a blog post, so I am instantiating it like this:

```
var controller = PostDetailController()
```

The problem is there is no navigation header or tab bars at the bottom. How do I properly start up my app from the beginning then load my `PostDetailController`?

Below is what my storyboard looks like and I'm trying to link directly to my "Post Detail Controller" but with all the previous controllers behind it, how do I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways you can implement this. Assuming you are starting from the app delegate's `openURL:` method, here is a high level view of one way to do it.

1. From the `openURL:` method, parse out the needed parameters from the `url` and store it in a global var.
2. Subclass your `UITabBarController` and create a function to handle the deep link. This function should evaluate the global var set in the app delegate and determine which Tab and view need to be displayed.

For example:

```
        // Check for deep link global var

        if (myGlobalVar==1){
            //Instantiate the destination view (the view you want the deep link to show)
            DetailViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myDetailView"];

            //set any vars need in the destination view

            //Push the detail View to stack of the to be seleceted Tab
            [[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:myTABINDEX] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];

            //select the tab to the destination view
            [self setSelectedIndex:myTABINDEX];

        }
```

Comment: Thx but I'm getting this error when trying it: `Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <MyProject.TabBarController..`

Comment: can you update your question to show the code you used and where you implemented it.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to deal with the Navigation Controller inside of the Tab Bar.

Comment: Based on the OP's question and setup, it's implied (#2) that the view to be displayed by the nav controller will need to be instantiate so it can be presented by the Navigation Controller. I the example code, the desired view is pushed to the top of the stack where `[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:myTABINDEX]` represents the nav controller.